# How to enable gzip compression in Orchard CMS

Tags: orchardcms

I looked into the Orchard CMS (version 1.10.3) source code and didn't find anywhere any line suggesting that http headers are set to Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate

Did I overlook something? 
How do you essentially enable gzip compression in the CMS?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, this is something you'd configure on IIS, not in Orchard itself. See [the IIS documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/httpcompression/) to find how to configure compression for both static and dynamic contents.

Comment: Yes, you're right, but I thought there might be some ways to control it within orchard itself rather that IIS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be configured in IIS, which supports compression for both dynamic and static contents. See [the IIS documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/httpcompression/) for full details.